# vba: Function that concatenates only visible cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"DA","NU"},'- - REZULTAT ANAF - -'!I4))),CONCATENATE('- - REZULTAT ANAF - -'!B4,""),"")
```

and it goes down to row 17000.

It concatenates cell B4 from sheet - - REZULTAT ANAF - -' to another sheet if I4 from sheet - - REZULTAT ANAF - -' ="DA" or "NU".

**I need a function that will do the same thing BUT it also determines if cell is visible (filtered) and concatenate only if it is visible (not filtered out).** (i managed to do this with a range but i need to do it cell by cell)

I could do the same thing by making it do: autofilter on the whole table and then just copy the whole results on the other sheet but being a table of 17000 full of formulas and macros that slows the excel alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a different sheet name, but this works for me:

```
=IF(AND(SUBTOTAL(103,Sheet2!I4),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"DA","NU"},Sheet2!I4)))),
    CONCATENATE(Sheet2!B4,""),
    "")
```

Comment: It works. Didn't even know that was possible with excel formula. Thank you.